# How to swap two indexed fields with laravel migrations?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

In the Models of a many to many relationship I have accidentally identified the foreign key names in reverse. This is done in both related Models so the relationship works. It's in production.

In `Articles`:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ArticleCategory::class, 'article_category_article', 'article_category_id', 'article_id');
}
```

and in `ArticleCategory`:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'article_category_article', 'article_id', 'article_category_id');
}
```

As you can see, both foreign keys are reversed.

It doesn't bother me because it works throughout the project. In the `article_category_article` table both values are recorded in the 'wrong' column.

But what *if* I'd like to swap it anyway. The Models are easy, but what about the pivot table? I have tried with a laravel migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('article_category_article', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('article_id', 'temporarily');
        $table->renameColumn('article_category_id', 'article_id');
        $table->renameColumn('temporarily', 'article_category_id');
    });
}
```

without success, it predictably runs into the error `There is no column with name 'temporarily' on table 'article_category_article'`

Splitting it up in 2 migration files ran into the same error.

I have the tendency to let it be. The question is: **can it be done?** I presume swapping the columns *inside* MySQL (without migrations), *re-index* the tables and *adapt* the Models is a possibility. Any ideas? I can test it out on a local server.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate queries work for me:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('article_category_article', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('article_id', 'temporarily');
        $table->renameColumn('article_category_id', 'article_id');
    });
    Schema::table('article_category_article', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('temporarily', 'article_category_id');
    });
}
```